# Why I cannot handle a EventHandler<XXX> with an EventHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

I have the following code trying to attach a generic event handler at run time:

```
EventInfo info = source.GetType().GetEvent("EventWithArgsInheritingFromEventArg");
info.AddEventHandler(source, new EventHandler((obj, args) => DoSomething()));
```

When I try to do that I get the following Exception:

> Object of type 'System.EventHandler' cannot be converted to type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridSortingEventHandler'.

It's my understanding that a method with a signature (object sender, EventArgs e) can handle any event with a parameter inheriting from EventArgs right?

What's wrong with my approach?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Can this make any difference? Could it happen that DaraGridSortingEventHandler does not inherit from EventHandler???

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is that covariance/contravariance bullshit? It sounds as if somewhere there is a downcast from EventHandler to DataGridSortingEventHandler..

Comment: @LewsTherin: could be. I always have a headache when I have to deal with these terms ...

Comment: Me too :( To try and solve it, maybe you should send in a derived type of DataGrid's event handler.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridsortingeventargs(v=vs.100).aspx) DataGridSortingEventArgs defenatly derives from EventArgs

Comment: Are you using .NET 4? Delegate object variance was only introduced in .NET 4...

Comment: @thecoop: yep, I'm using .Net4. Right.

Comment: @AviTurner: Talking about the handlers not the args ... thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use different delegates using the `AddEventHandler` method, but a workaround is to create a delegate using [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6.aspx) first:

```
EventInfo info = source.GetType().GetEvent("EventWithArgsInheritingFromEventArg");

// create the event handler
var eventhandler = new EventHandler(this.DoSomething);

// create a delegate from the EventHandler
var @delegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(info.EventHandlerType, null, eventhandler.Method);

info.AddEventHandler(source, @delegate);
```